# JS returning function not present

Tags: javascript

I have following code.

```
var handleJson = function(){
        var jsonData ='xx';
        var eventObject,eventObjectx=[];
        that = this;
        var convertJsonToObject = function(datax){
                //debugger;
                try {
                        that.printList(datax.data);
                    } catch(e) {
                      console.log(e);
                    }

                //debugger;
            }

        return{

            getDatafromserver: function(url){

                    $.ajax({
                        crossOrigin: true,
                        url: url,
                        success:convertJsonToObject
                            //console.log(jsonData);
                    });

            },

            printList:function(eventObject){

                $.each(eventObject,function(index,val){

                    $('#eventlist').append('<li>'+val.event+'</li>');
                })
            }

        }
    }


    var jsonHandler = new handleJson();

        jsonHandler.getDatafromserver(url);

        //jsonHandler.printList('eventlist');


});
```

Although the function `printList` exist its returning error

> TypeError: that.printList is not a function {stack: (...), message:
>   "that.printList is not a function"}

Can any one help me out?

Comment: It exists, but it's not assigned to `this` (or `that`).

Comment: @Juhana so what should be the right approach to do this, I know if i just get the List function outside the return and pass argument of the JsonObject , I can do that , But In this context how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` as of your `that = this` line is not in any way related to the object that you return at the end of your `handleJson` function.

Since you're using `new` with `handleJson`, you want to add to the object that `this` refers to, rather than returning a new, unrelated object:

```
var handleJson = function() {
    var jsonData = 'xx';
    var eventObject, eventObjectx = [];
    var that = this;
    var convertJsonToObject = function(datax) {
        //debugger;
        try {
            that.printList(datax.data);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

        //debugger;
    }

    this.getDatafromserver = function(url) {

        $.ajax({
            crossOrigin: true,
            url: url,
            success: convertJsonToObject
                //console.log(jsonData);
        });

    };

    this.printList = function(eventObject) {

        $.each(eventObject, function(index, val) {

            $('#eventlist').append('<li>' + val.event + '</li>');
        })
    };

};

var jsonHandler = new handleJson();

jsonHandler.getDatafromserver(url);

//jsonHandler.printList('eventlist');
```

Here's how `new` works:

- It creates a new object backed by the object that the target function's `prototype` property refers to; so in your case, a new object backed by `handleJson.prototype`.
- It calls the target function (`handleJson`) with `this` referring to that new object.
- When the target function returns, if it doesn't return anything, or it returns a primitive value, or it returns `null`, `new` takes the object that it created as its result; but if the target function returns a non-`null` object reference, that *overrides* that default and `new` takes that object reference as its result.

In your original code, that last point was coming into play.

---

Side note: Your code was falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) becuse you weren't declaring `that`. I've added `var` on it above.

---

Side note: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that a *constructor function* (a function you're calling via `new`) starts with a capital letter. They're also usually *nouns* rather than *verbs* (other kinds of functions are usually verbs, but not constructor functions, which are named after the thing they construct). So `JsonHandler` rather than `handleJson`.

Comment: @T.JCrowder okay , So In a closure which is defined like i did how will a function can access other function ? , Is that possible? , Or I should create a class and add those functions as prototype for them ?

Comment: I am just trying to learn the right approach to use OOPS in js

Comment: @Vikram: The updated code in the answer does that. You could put `printList` on the prototype; you can't put `getDataFromserver` on the prototype because in this code it wants to use the `convertJsonToObject` function you're defining in `handleJson`. You have variables and such you're not using in that function, so it's hard to suggest how it could be reformulated.

Comment: @TJCrowder alright I will use your approach from now onwards, So basically I am trying to work on a class/function which can Create,Add,Delete a list view of events . Just like we do it in the database